# IE filters don't display on duplicated element text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have been wracked for days trying to find why I can't use the MS blur & glow filters to generate a drop shadow in Internet Explorer as appearing on this page:

http://kilianvalkhof.com/uploads/ieshadow.html

Here, a second text element is positioned under the first element, offset a bit, and the filters applied.  My layout is using the same technique, for a drop shadow on the H1 element at the top, which shows fine in standards-compliant browsers, but the filtered element is not showing in IE8 or IE9:

http://a11.cosd.com

My markup uses a `<span>` like the working example:

```
<h1>AREA11<span class="IEshadow">AREA11</span></h1>
```

with CSS the same except for the selectors:

```
#headerContainer header h1 span.IEshadow {
  display: none;
}
.lt-ie10 #headerContainer header h1 span.IEshadow {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: -4px;
  z-index: -1;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=#000000,Strength=2) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.blur(pixelradius=5,enabled='true');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=#000000,Strength=2) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.blur(pixelradius=5,enabled='true')";
}
```

But in my layout the filters aren't applied at all, even though I can see the `filter:` properties ***are*** listed in IE8 and IE9 with the (F12) Developer Tools.  This isn't the first time I've used Visual Filters in a design, but in this case I've copied the code character by character.

One odd thing: when I view the `filter:` property in IE8 developer tools, it shows the other properties lumped together on the same line, though they appear normally in IE9 where the problem is still happening.

I have tried everything I can imagine, including disabling all other Javascripts from the page and simplifying the markup and CSS, as well as avoiding `font-face` and putting the `<span>` in IE conditional comments as in the working example... no change.  (I need to avoid the IE conditional comments to eventually implement this in jQuery.)

There must be something very basic I am missing here about why MS filters won't work in this context.  I will absolutely summarise any progress & findings here if my layout changes in the course of testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `z-index` issue. The `.IEshadow` is positioned behind the background.

Give your `h1` a `z-index` of 10 and it should work.

```css
#headerContainer header h1 {
    ...
    z-index: 10;
}
```

You might also want to change the color of `.IEshadow`

```css
.lt-ie10 #headerContainer header h1 span.IEshadow {
    ...
    color: #000000;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I see.  This would also have been an issue in the example page if there were a background on that page.  On my example there is a background, and with nothing to establish a new [stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) it has a z-index of 0.  Therefore the duplicated element displays behind it.  Thank you very much.  And you are also right that the shadow colour is taken from the element itself, not from the `Color=` argument of the filter, and it looks much better with black.  May you live long and prosper!